# Can the Path assigned a SQLite DB be an arbitrary value?

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps, app.xaml

In [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx), some prerequisite code for getting started using SQLite in Windows Store Apps is given, for adding to the OnLaunched method of App.xaml.cs:

```
// Get a reference to the SQLite database
this.DBPath = Path.Combine(
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "customers.sqlite");
```

My question is: Can I use any arbitrary value to replace the "customers.sqlite" part, or does it have to match something else in my code, such as the name of my table definition class (in my case "PhotraxCoreData.cs" which, according to Mr. Green's suggestion, I added below a newly-created "Models" folder)?

My understanding is that, once I've got those classes defined (I do), and the code above in App.xaml.cs, along with this there (adapted for my SQLite classes):

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
{
    // Create the tables if they don't exist
    db.CreateTable<PhotraxBaseData>();
    db.CreateTable<PhotraxNames>();
    db.CreateTable<PhotraxQueries>();
}
```

...SQLite tables based on those classes I specified will be created, and have the name "customers.sqlite" (provided I don't change it).

So, can I use:

```
this.DBPath = Path.Combine(
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "platypus.sqlite");
```

...or must it be something like:

```
this.DBPath = Path.Combine(
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "PhotraxCoreData.sqlite");
```

Comment: According to the video referenced in Robert Green's article, it is an arbitrary value - it can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That database name is just a file name.
The directory must be accessible by your app, but the file name can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

AS CL says, the file name can be anything the app has direct access to. Windows Store apps have limited access to the file system, so the sqlite database must be in either the apps install location (read only) or it's app data folder (read write). A common pattern is to ship a seed database in the app package and then copy it from the install location to app data on first use so it can be written to.

Comment: In the case of SQLite in Windows Store apps, I believe by setting things up the way RG demonstrates will automatically generate the database and its tables in the app data folder...right? It works for me on my dev machine that way, and I'm assuming/hoping it will work that way on user's machines, too.

Comment: Yes. You can create a database programmatically in the app data directory since you have read+ write access there.